# Export number of list items within a div on a page to another page

Tags: php, html, html-lists, return

I'm looking for a way to do the following with PHP.

There are multiple pages within folder /section/. red.html, blue.html, green.html. And there is an index.html page in the root of the server.

On each of these pages, there is the div with the id "list" containing a ul with list items. How can I retrieve the number of list items within this div on each of the pages in /section/ and return the number for each one on the index.html page.

To better illustrate it:

The structure on each page:

```
<div id="list">
<ul>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
</div>

    red.html (33 list items within #list)
    blue.html (20 list items within #list)
    green.html (15 list items within #list)

    index.html:

    **Stats:**
    Red: <php here fetching the number from red.html>
    Blue: <php here fetching the number from blue.html>
    Green: <php here fetching the number from green.html>
```

Comment: so you want to use php to grab li from all these pages and show them on a single page. Is that what you want ??

Comment: I'm trying to find a way to fetch the total number of li on each individual page within the div, and returning the total count to the index.html page in the root. If there are 20 list items within #list on red.html, I'd like the number to display on the index.html page in the root.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have some options here. `.html` suggests we're talking about static html files, so let's work with that.

1.) Because it's all static, you need to open these files and parse them (manually or maybe using some 3rd party library, if there exists such). Then you just output the results.

2.) Transform static html files to php and html lists to arrays. In your red, blue and green files you'll need to enumerate through these arrays and simply output them to get the same effect. But, in your index.php all you need to do is to include these files and get the information directly from these arrays that became available. I believe you know how to get number of elements of an array, right?

EDIT:

As requested in comments, I'll try to show you an example. Probably the easiest way here is to use the second option.. Instead of using statically typed html lists, create php variables - arrays - containing your items. If you need to display these items, simply loop over this collection and echo as needed. If you need to get number of elements in an array, simply use a php function `count(...)`

Example of displaying items:

red.php

```
$someArray = array("one", "two", "three");

foreach ($someArray as $i -> $value)
{
    echo '<li>'.$value'.<li>';
}
```

index.php

```
include_once 'red.php';

echo 'Count of elements in red.php: '.count($someArray);
```

Or something like that, hope you get the idea.

Comment: Yes, they're all static without a CMS or anything. Unfortunately, I'm only familiar with HTML/CSS and I'm still just beginning with languages like PHP. I have my .htaccess set to allow me to include PHP in my html files, however, I'm not familiar enough to understand exactly what you're telling me. Could you try explaining with some examples step by step? I'm sorry if I'm asking too much.

Comment: @Nux, I've just added an example, hope it's a bit clearer now.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply, and I'm not positive of all the PHP terminology just yet, but I think I understand. Your example helps a lot, and I'll try the code now to see if I have the correct understanding. Thank you for explaining again.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following in your index but it would have to use PHP so youd need to rename it to index.php.

```
$sections = new DirectoryIterator('/path/to/sections');
$stats = array();

foreach($sections as $file) {
  if(!$file->isDot() && $file->isFile()) {
     $name = $file->getName();
     $path = $file->getPathname();
     $key =  str_replace('.html', '', $name);

     // load the html
     $dom = new DOMDocument();
     $dom->loadHTML($path);

     // get the LI of the list via xpath query
     $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
     $elements = $xpath->query("//ul[@id='list']/li");

     // assign the stat
     $stats[$key] = $elements->length;

     // free up some memory
     unset($elements, $xpath, $dom);
  }
}
```

After that you jsut need to iterate over `$stats` and output your counts. So something like:

```
<dl>
<?php foreach($stats as $label => $count): ?>
  <dt><?php echo $label ?></dt>
  <dd><?php echo $count ?></dd>
<?php endforeach ?>
</dl>
```